# Are not stored solr fields stored as encrypted data at rest?

Tags: encryption, solr

If solr puts my documents in an index that include personally identifiable information, will the index files contain meaningful information that would allow someone to read the documents in plain text from the disk (i.e. at rest)?

Answer (score 2):

Solr will not encrypt the information stored in the index file.
So a person, who have access to the index files or your solr environment could copy the index files or whole solr environment in order to run the index/solr installation on an different host to walk/read trough the index.

Comment: so, would a <directoryFactory class="org.apache.solr.core.RAMDirectoryFactory"/> ensure that only a user that had access to RAM would be able to read the data?